# Bash | Read a file line by line

Tags: bash

I am using a while loop in bash to read a file line by line. I have been doing it for years but now stuck with a weird problem.

Here is my code

```
while read -r i
do
echo $i
done < input.dat
```

My input file contains 2 lines with '|' as a delimiter

```
 Cars|bikes|This is a test 
 Oranges|Apples|Another test
```

For the first iteration the string printed is:

```
 Cars|bikes|This is a test
```

But for the second iteration the string printed is:

```
Oranges Apples Another test
```

Note how the pipes are replaced by whitespaces for all iterations but the first one ?

I cant seem to figure out the why ?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior.  If I run your script with your input, everything displays as expected.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible. Setting `IFS="|"` would explain the output of the second line, but you would have to have done that in the body of the `while` loop (after the `echo`) to avoid splitting the first line of output.

Comment: Inside the while loop i am doing few stuff like processing a json object, calling a rest api with curl as well, but nothing to do with the variable 'i' of the while loop. 
And you guys are right, if i do a while loop normally without the logic, it runs fine.